# Wordpress uses wrong PHP version

Tags: php, versions, wordpress

WordPress appears to be using PHP7.1 despite 7.3 being installed.
Seems to be a lot of questions about this problem, but no cohesive way to deal with it…

I have just setup a new server on AWS (Ubuntu 18). It came pre-packaged with PHP, mysql, and WordPress. I ran `apt upgrade` and this seems to have installed PHP7.3.

`php -v` shows

> PHP 7.3.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar 20 2020 13:51:46) ( NTS )

But for some reason I get a warning in wordpress because it seems to be using PHP 7.1.
Is there a clear set of instructions to follow which I can use to switch wordpress over to use PHP7.3?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have installed both versions of PHP,

1. the PHP version provided by default by the AWS Ubuntu 18,
2. the PHP version provided by the third-party repository deb.sury.org.

However, whichever version is used by your Web server, is the version that is configured in there. 
For example, if you are using `nginx`, then check the configuration file of the server block, where it says the following. You need to find the correct Unix socket for the third-party PHP package, and replace `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` with the proper Unix socket. Finally, restart the Web server.

```
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure where I need to look for that file... Had a look in /etc but nothing there for nginx. Could you advise more on where I need to be making that change?

Comment: This is the configuration for the _server block (virtual host)_, and you can find it in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.